# Database-first OData service

Tags: .net, odata

I am familiar with building OData services in C# but, to my knowledge, they require lots of scaffolding (POCO classes, controllers, etc. for each entity). This can be hard to create and maintain for a database with a relatively large number of tables.

I am looking for a solution that puts the database first, either by statically generating code or dynamically at runtime, and exposes all the tables/views via an OData service.

Is there something like that available on the .NET ecosystem?

Note that I am aware of this post: [Dynamic odata service in C# from runtime data layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981931/dynamic-odata-service-in-c-sharp-from-runtime-data-layer?rq=2). It is far from a production ready OData service, doesn't implement support for query options like $filter, $expand, etc, or insert/update/delete operations.